# How to generate an error when File.Copy VB.net method tries to copy files

Tags: vb.net, file

I want to generate an exclusive error when File.Copy method executed.
However, is it possible? When my code worked and I opened a file in explorer, copy was succeeded. If I lock file, File.copy doesn't give any errors?

My Code:

```
Try
        If Directory.Exists(stDestPath) Then
            'Directory.Delete(stDestPath, True)
            Dim delDir As System.IO.DirectoryInfo = New System.IO.DirectoryInfo(stDestPath)
            Dim delFileInfos() As System.IO.FileSystemInfo = delDir.GetFileSystemInfos("*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)

            For Each delFileInfo As System.IO.FileSystemInfo In delFileInfos
                If ((delFileInfo.Attributes And System.IO.FileAttributes.Directory) = System.IO.FileAttributes.Directory) Then
                    delFileInfo.Attributes = System.IO.FileAttributes.Directory
                Else
                    delFileInfo.Attributes = System.IO.FileAttributes.Normal
                End If
            Next
            delDir.Delete(True)
        End If

        If System.IO.Directory.Exists(stDestPath) = False Then
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(stDestPath)
            System.IO.File.SetAttributes(stDestPath, System.IO.File.GetAttributes(stSourcePath))
            bOverwrite = True
        End If

        If bOverwrite Then
            For Each stCopyFrom As String In System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(stSourcePath)
                If stCopyFrom.IndexOf("ReleaseEnd.") <> -1 Then
                    Continue For
                End If

                Dim stCopyTo As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(stDestPath, System.IO.Path.GetFileName(stCopyFrom))
                System.IO.File.Copy(stCopyFrom, stCopyTo, True)
            Next stCopyFrom

        Else
            For Each stCopyFrom As String In System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(stSourcePath)
                If stCopyFrom.IndexOf("ReleaseEnd.") <> -1 Then
                    Continue For
                End If

                Dim stCopyTo As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(stDestPath, System.IO.Path.GetFileName(stCopyFrom))
                If System.IO.File.Exists(stCopyTo) = False Then
                    System.IO.File.Copy(stCopyFrom, stCopyTo, False) ***This Line***
                End If
            Next stCopyFrom
        End If

        For Each stCopyFrom As String In System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(stSourcePath)
            Dim stCopyTo As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(stDestPath, System.IO.Path.GetFileName(stCopyFrom))
            copyDirectory(stCopyFrom, stCopyTo, bOverwrite)
        Next stCopyFrom

    Catch ex As Exception
        TrapException.ServiceErrorProc(ex)
        Thread.CurrentThread.Abort()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: If an exception wasn't thrown then presumably the copy was successful.

Comment: _If I lock file_ How are you locking the file?  Opening it in another program?  You will find that depending on the file and different application, this actually doesn't "lock" the file so your test may actually be invaild

Comment: I just opened the file and I thought it generates file lock, but copy succeeded. Is there any way to disturb File.copy by exclusive error?

Comment: A text file will not be locked if you open it in Notepad, for instance. An Office file, e.g. XLSX or DOCX, should be locked if you open and edit it, I think. If it's the destination file you're talking about then you should be able to set the `Read-only` attribute via File Explorer to prevent over-writing.

Comment: @John read only will definitely generate a error, but doubt it would be the same as being locked

Comment: You could always write your own little app that opens the file exclusively .  You haven’t disclosed what type of file you’re dealing with though.